# Анимация блика кнопки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь скопировать анимацию кнопки "Поехали" вот [с этого сайта](https://www.marquiz.ru/#popup:marquiz_602e0c48ddadb2004472b009). Получается медленнее и зависает в конце. Что не так? Код вроде бы одинаковый.

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap B<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger text-truncate flex-even me-sm-3 position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>undle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
.btn-danger:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1)),color-stop(20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2)),to(hsla(0,0%,100%,.6)));
        background: linear-gradient(90deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1) 10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2) 20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.6));
        width: 20px;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
        transform: skewX(-45deg);
        left: -20%;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
        transition: all .6s ease;
        -webkit-animation-name: blick;
        animation-name: blick;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
        animation-duration: 6s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
```

Comment: Если вам нетрудно, не могли бы вы оценить решение

Answer (score 3):

Я предложу два варианта:

*Первый вариант ваш(только рабочий):*

```css
.position-relative:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1)),color-stop(20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2)),to(hsla(0,0%,100%,.6)));
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1) 10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2) 20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.6));
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    left: -20%;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-animation-name: blick;
    animation-name: blick;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blick {
0% { left: -30px; margin-left: 0px; }
30% { left: 110%; margin-left: 80px; }
100% { left: 110%; margin-left: 80px; } 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap B<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger text-truncate flex-even me-sm-3 position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>undle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

> Получается медленнее и зависает в конце

*И второй вариант мой, где включает ваши требования:*

```css
.position-relative:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,color-stop(10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1)),color-stop(20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2)),to(hsla(0,0%,100%,.6)));
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1) 10%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.2) 20%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.6));
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    left: -20%;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-animation-name: blick;
animation-name: blick;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
animation-delay: 0.05s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes blick{
0% { left: -30px; margin-left: 0px; }
30% { left: 110%; margin-left: 80px; }
100% { left: 110%; margin-left: 80px; } 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap B<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger text-truncate flex-even me-sm-3 position-relative" >Оценить автомобиль</button>undle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит вариант с использованием `blick:`  `slideme`? это же просто придуманные вами имена анимаций, а не свойства атрибутов, правил CSS.  За решение (+) и автору было бы неплохо немного компенсировать потраченную репу на конкурс

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Точно, вы совершенно правы, я уже забыл, давно использовал `css` и `html`. Спасибо вам за замечание! Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 1):

ну так а саму анимацию прописали:

```
@keyframes blick {
    15%,to {
        left: 110%
    }
}
```

Comment: увы, но это не помогло.